# SQL Specify 2 different conditions for 2 different columns in where clause with both having to be true

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, where-clause

How can i write an sql query to only return rows from a table

where for example column A is not null AND columb B is not 0

the way i am writing it is:

```
where A is not null AND B !=0
```

but the problem is that the query result is also eliminating rows where only one of the conditions is true such as column a being null but column b being anything but 0 & vice versa

I need the query to only eliminate (not return) the rows where BOTH conditions of my where clause are met.

I only want the result i get from query to be rows from the table where column A is not NUll and column B IS NOT = 0 but i need BOTH conditions to be met not just one of them

Comment: @armit Bhargave I don't want any rows to be eliminated because of my where clause if only 1 of the conditions are true. I only want the row to not be returned if both conditions are true (for a particular row of the table). I am getting to few records because rows where only 1 condition are met are also not being returned

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted this Answer on here but then they deleted it (not sure why?) but their answer worked and it was.

```
WHERE NOT(A is null AND B=0)
```

i tried using

```
where A is not null AND B <> 0
```

and

```
where (A is not null AND B <> 0)
```

but the where clause would be triggered even if only 1 of the conditions was met and I needed it to be triggered only when both conditions where met.

So again, the answer to my questions was using the below code.

```
WHERE NOT(A is null AND B=0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for:

```
where A is not null AND B <> 0
```

If your where clause actually is more complicated (e.g., also has an `OR` in it), then put brackets around the above, e.g.:

```
where (A is not null AND B <> 0) OR ...
```

Comment: I think it should be OR B = 0

Comment: I only want the result i get from query to be rows from the table where column A is not NUll and column B IS NOT = 0 

but i need BOTH conditions to be met not just one of them

Answer (score 1):

> I need the query to ... *not* return the rows where BOTH
>   conditions of my where clause are met.

It sounds like you want to negate the WHERE clause. Like so:

```
WHERE NOT (A IS NOT NULL AND B !=0)
```

This can be rewritten without the double negative:

```
WHERE (A IS NULL OR B = 0 OR B IS NULL)
```

Comment: I ended up having to use the WHERE NOT clause as you suggested but i didn't want my results to include any rows where A was null AND B = 0 so i had to use  WHERE NOT(A is null AND B=0)